# Can we define an ordered pair as $(a,b)=\{a,\{b\}\}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can we define an ordered pair as $(a,b)=\{a,\{b\}\}$?
It seems like a good definition to me. It fits,
$$(a_1,b_1)=(a_2,b_2)\iff (a_1=a_2 )\wedge(b_1=b_2)  $$

Comment: You need to provide the details for the other case so a comparison can be made

Comment: This question facilitated a good answer it should not be closed or downvoted

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> It fits
> $(a_1,b_1)=(a_2,b_2)\iff (a_1=a_2 )\wedge(b_1=b_2)$.

No, it does not. For example, under this definition:

$$(\{\varnothing\},\{\varnothing\}) = \{\{\varnothing\},\{\{\varnothing\}\}\} = \{\{\{\varnothing\}\},\{\varnothing\}\} = (\{\{\varnothing\}\},\varnothing).$$